# Moving elements from one ArrayList to another

Tags: java, arraylist

The directions in my lesson are: Complete the definition below for a static method transplantBlock which, for any non-negative integer n, removes a block of n elements from an ArrayList fromList starting from the element at index start and inserts them (in order) into an ArrayList toList starting at index target. (If there are fewer than n elements from the element with index start to the end of fromList, then the method transplants the entire "tail" of the ArrayList from the element with index start to the end.)

So far I have this:

```
public static void transplantBlock( ArrayList<String> fromList,
                                    ArrayList<String> toList,
                                    int start,
                                    int target,
                                    int n ) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if ( fromList.size() > start) {
            fromList.remove(start);            
        }  
    }
}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
  String[] fromData = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k" };
  ArrayList<String> fromList = new ArrayList<String>();
  for ( int i = 0; i < fromData.length; i++ )
    fromList.add( fromData[ i ] );

  String[] toData = { "z", "y", "x", "w", "v", "u", "t", "s" };
  ArrayList<String> toList = new ArrayList<String>();
  for ( int i = 0; i < toData.length; i++ )
    toList.add( toData[ i ] );

  transplantBlock( fromList, toList, 6, 3, 4 );

  System.out.println( "After:" );
  System.out.println( "   fromList: " + fromList );
  System.out.println( "   toList: " + toList );
}
```

The output should be this:

```
After:
   fromList: [a, b, c, d, e, f, k]
   toList: [z, y, x, g, h, i, j, w, v, u, t, s]
```

I'm able to remove the correct elements from fromList, but I can't figure out how to add them to toList.  If somebody could help me figure out what I'm missing, I'd be very grateful.  Thank you!

(Sidenote: This is fill-in-the-blank assignment, so this isn't a class issue)

Comment: Use `ArrayList#add(int index, E element)`.  Keep incrementing the target index for each element you inserted.  that's it

Comment: So, you figured out somehow that to remove an element from a list, you need to do `remove`, but have no idea what to try when you want to add an element. Really?

Comment: I've tried adding elements to the arraylist and it keeps telling me that it's the improper use of the add function, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: "improper use"? I don't think so. What exactly did you try (why don't you show the code?) and what exactly was the error you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping track of the index where to insert the element you just removed:

```
int insertIndex = target;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (fromList.size() > start) {
        String removed = fromList.remove(start);
        toList.add(insertIndex, removed);
        insertIndex++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing other people's homework is bad taste :-/ ... regardless of any particular website genre. Downvote means the answer is not useful, which yours definitely isn't.

Comment: Thank you for this, I didn't use your exact code but I was able to read each step of the process and I actually understand what do now.  And Dima, sometimes backwards learning like this helps more than vague answers.  This is also part of my lesson, not a homework assignment; I get no points for completing this.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `add(int index, E element)` method in `List`

It should look something like:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d"));

myList.add(2, "x");

// List should look like [a, b, x, c, d] now
```

The rest should be trivial.

Comment: Thank you for this, I figured out what I was screwing up with the add method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void transplantBlock( ArrayList<String> fromList,
                                    ArrayList<String> toList,
                                    int start,
                                    int target,
                                    int n )


   {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
        if (fromList.size() > start)
         {
            String removed = fromList.remove(start);
            toList.add(target, removed);
            target++;
        }
    }
   }


 public static void main( String[] args )
{
  String[] fromData = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k" };
  ArrayList<String> fromList = new ArrayList<String>();
  for ( int i = 0; i < fromData.length; i++ )
    fromList.add( fromData[ i ] );

  String[] toData = { "z", "y", "x", "w", "v", "u", "t", "s" };
  ArrayList<String> toList = new ArrayList<String>();
  for ( int i = 0; i < toData.length; i++ )
    toList.add( toData[ i ] );

  transplantBlock( fromList, toList, 6, 3, 4 );

  System.out.println( "After:" );
  System.out.println( "   fromList: " + fromList );
  System.out.println( "   toList: " + toList );
}
```